# Is there a way to retrieve all the parameters(even nested or in array) from a Swagger File using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, openapi

Is there a way Read and extract data like parameters from a swagger file ? I'm using the Petstore Swagger ( https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json)
There are references used inside the definitions for parameters. However, in the definition for "Pet", the definition for "Category" is defined in a separate definition.

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to extract the data from json file as an object ?

Comment: I would like to extract all the Paths and its respective Parameters from a Swagger file.

Answer (score 3):

The Question is really unclear.Anyhow I will try.

In Swagger, API operation parameters are defined under the parameters section in the operation definition. Each parameter has name, value type (for primitive value parameters) or schema (for request body)

Assuming you need to acces the parameters from swagger you just need to access the swagger object from the request object. ie you can access a particluar url parameter as

```
param_name = req.swagger.params['param_name'].value
```

also if you need the json request body for the put or post request you can access by accessing body object from params

```
param_name = req.swagger.params.body.value['param_name']
```

**you can find all the parameters in  the params object in**

```
params = req.swagger.params
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response.  But in the petstore example, the parameter for the Path "/Pet" contains a body parameter which contains the reference to parameter definitions